# $〈A,B〉≤n‖A‖_2‖B‖_2$ matrix computation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, svd, singular-values

Show that for two matrices $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ we have $\langle A,B\rangle\leq n\|A\|_2\|B\|_2$.

I was hinted to use the SVD decomposition of $A$. I have $\|A\|_2 := \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|_2$ and $\langle A, B \rangle := tr(AB^T) = tr(U\Sigma V^T B^T)$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: How do you define the norm $\|A\|_2$?

Comment: $\lVert A \rVert_2 := \sup\limits_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r= \min(m,n)$, and $\|M\|_F =\sqrt{tr (MM^\top)}$ denote the Frobenius norm of $M\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$. Then it holds $$\langle A,B \rangle \leq \|A\|_F \|B\|_F \leq \sqrt{r}\|A\|_2\,\sqrt{r}\|B\|_2=r\|A\|_2\|B\|_2,$$
where the first inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwartz. The second inequality follows from the [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence) between $\|.\|_2$ and $\|\cdot \|_F$.

---

*Proof of* $\|M\|_F \leq \sqrt{r}\|M\|_2$:

Let $M\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ and $U,\Sigma, V$ an SVD of $M$, then we have
$$\|M\|_F =\sqrt{tr (U\Sigma\Sigma^\top U^T)}=\sqrt{tr (\Sigma\Sigma^\top U^TU)}=\sqrt{\sum_{i} \Sigma_{ii}^2}\\\leq \sqrt{r\max_i\Sigma_{ii}^2}=\sqrt{r}\|M\|_2.$$

Comment: Thank you. Quick question should I rather say $\lvert\langle A, B \rangle\rvert \le \lVert A \rVert_F \lVert B \rVert_F$ or $\langle A, B \rangle \le \lVert A \rVert_F \lVert B \rVert_F$ is also okay?

Comment: @roi_saumon It doesn't really matter since $-\langle A,B\rangle = \langle (-A),B\rangle$ and $\|A\|_F = \|-A\|_F$.